# Как удалить пустые строки в List?

Tags: java, list

Нужно удалить пустые строки в листе, однако на .remove() выдает ошибку
как можно грамотно это записать?
вот фрагмент кода:

```
private static List<String> deleteEmptyStringLoop(List<String> strings) {
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = strings.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
            String element = iterator.next();
            if("".equals((element))) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        return strings;
    }

public static void main (String[] args) {
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("abc", "", "bc", "efg", "abcd", "", "jk1"); 

System.out.println(Streams.deleteEmptyStringStream(strings));
System.out.println(Streams.deleteEmptyStringLoop(strings));
```

Comment: с минимальными и не очень рациональными изменениями оберните принимаемый аргумент List<String> strings в ArrayList , используя конструктор коллекции: new ArrayList<>(strings ). Вы получите лист, из которого сможете удалить элементы. Но , учитывая, что при вызове этого метода вы постоянно конвертируете массив в лист, проще принимать сразу массив и вместо аргумента  List<String> strings принимать String ... strings. Дальше либо стримом, как указано в ответе ниже, либо создавать лист и добавлять в него нужные элементы, итерируясь по массиву, возвращая из метода данный лист

Answer (score 3):

Всё дело в том, что `Arrays.asList()` возвращает обертку над массивом, а массивы в джаве всегда фиксированные. Поэтому такие операции как `remove()`, `add()` не будут работать, т.к. они предполагают изменение размера массива.

Нужно просто обернуть список в любой другой изменяемый список:

```
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("abc", "", "bc", "efg", "abcd", "", "jk1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто отфильтруйте

```
List<String> notEmpty = Arrays.asList("abc", "", "bc", "efg", "abcd", "", "jk1")
    .stream()
    .filter(item -> !item.equals(""))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: так делать нехорошо: !item.equals(""). для этого есть методы isEmpty, isBlank. кроме того, какой смысл вызывать Arrays.asList, получая из массива лист, для того, чтобы следующим шагом преобразовать его в стрим. Почему сразу не получить стрим, например, так: Stream.of("abc", "", "bc", "efg", "abcd", "", "jk1")

Comment: @Дмитрий да, все так, однако это ученический вопрос, мой ответ максимально простой для понимания что откуда берется а нюансы методов String второстепенно в данном контексте. А Stream.of сама IDE подскажет что можно сократить важно чтобы человек понял идею.